# Cómo dar el formato de fecha correcto?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, formato

ante todo muchas gracias por su constante aporte y ayuda para ser un mejor desarrollador.
Mi inquietud es la siguiente: tengo que formatear la fecha y estas son las variables de formato de fecha, pero me toma el formato incorrecto en algunas búsquedas como por ej

[image: muestraImagenFecha]

```
    let formatFecDesde = encodeURIComponent(Moment(this.state.fechaDesde).format('YYYYMMDD'));
    let formatFecHasta = encodeURIComponent(Moment(this.state.fechaHasta).format('YYYYMMDD'));

    <DateBox id="fechaDesde" defaultValue={this.state.fechaDesde} type="date" 
    displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"  onValueChanged={this.cambioFechaDesde} />
```

Este es mi formato de código ↑
He intentado agregar los guiones y las barras cambiar el orden de los valores a DD-MM-YYYY y DD/MM/YYYY pero esas soluciones no dieron resultados positivos.
Que formato puedo darles para su correcta visualización?

Comment: Perdón por la pregunta pero no me quedóc claro, el formato que estás buscando ¿es DD/MM/YY? De ser así, ¿cuál es el formato que obtienes con el código que muestras?

Comment: Hola! Si el formato que busco es DD/MM/YYYY y el formato que muestra el codigo es en algunos casos, MM/DD/YYYY, no es todos los resultados me da DD/MM/YYYY, eso me desconcierta más aún, no se como obligar a que suceda el formato DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar la configuración de locale -puede ser global o solo al momento de formatear-, en este caso se usa `es-mx` (puedes consultar en la [documentación](https://momentjs.com/) si alguno de los formatos en español se ajusta a tus necesidades).
2. Crear tu propio formato, en este caso se aplica directo, pero podrías crear una función para refactorizar el código repetido.

```js
console.log('Locale:', moment.locale());
console.log(moment().format('L')); // MM/DD/YYYY

console.log('Locale:', moment.locale());
console.log(moment().locale('es-mx').format('L')); // DD/MM/YYYY

console.log('Locale:', moment.locale());
console.log(moment().format('DD[/]MM[/]YYYY')); // DD/MM/YYYY
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

En el ejemplo anterior, si te das cuenta la configuración locale global siempre permanece en `en`. La primera fecha se muestra en el locale `en` dando como resultado **MM/DD/YYYY**. La segunda fecha aplica el locale `es-mx` para el formato dando como resultado **DD/MM/YYYY**. La tercera fecha "ignora" el locale e independientemente de él, *forza* a que el formato de salida sea **DD/MM/YYYY**.

Si lo deseas, puedes modificar la configuración locale de forma global llamando a esa función una única vez antes de realizar cualquier operación. Podría ser, inmediatamente después de incluir el script de moment.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el formato de la fecha cuando hagas la consulta sql de esta manera:

```
DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y' o '%d/%m/%Y')
```